# Product List Widget

Tags: magento2, cms, widgets

I tried to add product list widget to show all the products which have a special price but it gives me the following error.

> Error filtering template: Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 298 of 329 bytes in /home/..../public_html/vendor/magento/module-widget/Helper/Conditions.php on line 34

```
<p>{{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" title="iyi" show_pager="0" products_count="10" template="product/widget/content/grid.phtml" conditions_encoded="a:2:[i:1;a:4:[s:4:type;s:50:Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Combine;s:10:aggregator;s:3:all;s:5:value;s:1:1;s:9:new_child;s:0:``;]s:4:1--1;a:4:[s:4:type;s:50:Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Product;s:9:attribute;s:13:special_price;s:8:operator;s:1:`&
```

Please suggest

My version is Magento 2.1.8

Comment: Could you add the code you are using to call in the widget into your question? A where have you added your code into? I'm assuming it's a CMS Page or Block, but it would be helpful to know.

Comment: <p>{{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" title="iyi" show_pager="0" products_count="10" template="product/widget/content/grid.phtml" conditions_encoded="a:2:[i:1;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Combine`;s:10:`aggregator`;s:3:`all`;s:5:`value`;s:1:`1`;s:9:`new_child`;s:0:``;]s:4:`1--1`;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Product`;s:9:`attribute`;s:13:`special_price`;s:8:`operator`;s:1:`&

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you have the memory limit set to anything less than 2G in the .htaccess?

You may see something like 256M, 768M, but Magento is recommending 2G.

---

**Update**

Review error and debug logs, post applicable errors to provide more information.

Logs to check:

1. httpd logs (apache/nginx)
2. PHP logs - such as `error.log`
3. Magento's logs:  `./var/log/*` and `./var/report/*`

---

**update 2**

Wouldnt hurt to ensure that there are not some improper characters that cannot be parsed by the serialize.  Check all quotes, spaces, line terminations, etc... for any input you have inserted.  You need to be sure that if you have copied code or text from somewhere that it did not contain any unsupported ascii characters.

Comment: It was 1024 and I have changed it to 2048 and still give me the same message

Comment: Please check the following two files https://app.box.com/s/4xikpm3ulay5zsgo4ii542mjrh2idl4h and https://app.box.com/s/zt2dlok27oe1cmkajh0efp3oawnj89dy to check the error log

Comment: I have the following error in the error_log, Iam still have the problem and can't add product list widget[15-Apr-2018 12:18:47 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Widget\Helper\Conditions::serialize() in /home/comfortegypt/public_html/vendor/magento/module-widget/Helper/Conditions.php:21
Stack trace:


#0 /home/comfortegypt/public_html/vendor/magento/module-widget/Model/Widget.php(306): Magento\Widget\Helper\Conditions-

Comment: Please, advice I have magento 2.1.8 and trying to add catalog product list widget (price greater than 100) but it gives me the following error, some conditions are working and another gives me the error below.
Error filtering template: Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 81 of 305 bytes in /.../public_html/vendor/magento/module-widget/Helper/Conditions.php on line 34

Comment: Please, advice I have magento 2.1.8 and trying to add catalog product list widget (price greater than 100) but it gives me the following error, some conditions are working and another gives me the error below.

Comment: Error filtering template: Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 81 of 305 bytes in /.../public_html/vendor/magento/module-widget/Helper/Conditions.php on line 34

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked 9 months before, but anyone still look for the properly serialize string then here it is:

```
^[`1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Combine`,`aggregator`:`all`,`value`:`1`,`new_child`:``^],`1--1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Product`,`attribute`:`special_price`,`operator`:`&gt;`,`value`:`0`^]^]
```

The above code will list all products which  has special price greater than 0